# Are saves portable?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a minecraft game going on a Mac laptop.  Assuming the minecraft version is the same, would it be possible to transfer this save to a Windows PC and continue playing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The world saves are done in the same format, so to transfer a world you just need to copy the folder with the name of your world across.

This can usually be found here on macs: `(username)/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves`

Copy the entire folder to your windows files. Windows file structure depends on version but commonly it's found at: `C:/users/(username)/appdata/roaming/.minecraft/saves`

`appdata` May be an invisible folder by default, you can make it visible by changing your settings in the windows file viewer.

Comment: And using sym links would make this folder automatically synced with dropbox.  Or would this potentially cause problems? (I could see this if the saves are continually modified.  Are they just modified when you click save, or does MC write to them continually?)  I've used GameSave Manager on Windows in the past (supports dropbox saves), but it's Windows only.

Comment: Alternatively if you want an easier way to open up appdata on windows, you can press the Windows key + R and type in `%appdata%`

Comment: I believe single player saves are run on exiting the game, although I'm not certain, there may also be periodic saving. I am sure it doesn't constantly write to the save.

Comment: You can *automatically sync* with Dropbox?!

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach yes, just keep the actual file on dropbox, and add a symlink in the game directory. Sometimes a hard link might be a better idea.

Comment: @TimCoker At the time Minecraft SP and Multi didn't share the server interface, it would only save (somethings) when you paused the game. The server saved at a specific time interval. Nowadays, I think Minecraft has been implemented with the server inbuilt in SP. At any rate, I wouldn't recommend syncing with Dropbox. Mostly because of personal preference, but when 2 programs have read-write access to any file, weird things can happen, such as Dropbox overriding your save because it thinks it has the most up-to-date version of a possibly corrupted file. Do the backup when you leave the game.

Comment: @Lohoris Whenever I share saves via Dropbox, I do what you seem to call "hard links." Can the reverse work? (so that the actual file is in the directory, and the symlink is on Dropbox?)

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach if you do an actual [hard link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) those two files are identical, there's no more original and link. If you instead do a symlink no, the original have to be in dropbox, you can't do the reverse.